# WPF RichTextBox: How to add different colors in a single sentence in Run(text)?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a client talking to a server. The server may may send back the buffer as "Bob: Is anyone here?" You can think of it like a chatroom.

Prior to the first occurrence of ':', I would like to make this word green. Everything to the right of ':' will stay white.

How can I do this? I found this not to be so straight-forward.

This writes an incoming text message to the RichTextBox:

```
public void WriteLine(string text)
{
    Paragraph para = new Paragraph(); 

    // Buffer output
    para.Inlines.Add(new Run(text));

    // Add block
    txtOutput.Document.Blocks.Add(para);

    // Always keep scrolled to the end
    txtOutput.ScrollToEnd();

    // Clear input field.
    txtInput.Clear();

    // Focus back on the input field.
    txtInput.Focus();
}
```

My attempt:

```
// Output buffer
para.Inlines.Add(new Run { Text = text, Foreground = Brushes.Green, FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold });
```

The problem with doing it this way is the whole line will be green. What I need is this format:

Name (Green): Output (White).

Please let me know. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Prior to the first occurrence of ':', I would like to make this word green. Everything to the right of ':' will stay white.*

Based on your requirement in question, all you need to do is to split the text and add two Run to your Paragraph.

Check the below code.

```
public void WriteLine(string text)
{
    Paragraph para = new Paragraph();

    //Split the content from text

    var content = text.Split(':');

    // Buffer output
    para.Inlines.Add(new Run { Text = content[0] + ": ", Foreground = Brushes.Green, FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold });
    para.Inlines.Add(new Run { Text = content[1], Foreground = Brushes.White, FontWeight = FontWeights.Regular });

    // Add block
    txtOutput.Document.Blocks.Add(para);

    // Always keep scrolled to the end
    txtOutput.ScrollToEnd();

    //// Clear input field.
    //txtInput.Clear();

    //// Focus back on the input field.
    //txtInput.Focus();
}
```